# foreground color wont be changed in controlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, foreground

I am using WPF. Please look at comment related to Foreground in code. When the textbox gets focused, the font should be changed to white but it is not working. Why?

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#FFDCDCC9" Background="#FFDCDCC9" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                        <Setter  Property="Background" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFB5266E"/>
                        <Setter  Property="Background" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                        <!-- foreground is invalid --> 
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" TargetName="bg" Value="white"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Is your `IsMouseOver` trigger overriding the `IsFocused` Trigger?

Comment: The TargetName="bg" looks like it is targeting the Border element. What happens when you remove the TargetName="bg" designation?

Comment: @Evanlewis yes correct

Comment: @KristianK if TargetName is removed, color background and borderbrush of IsMouseOver and IsFocused is gone....

Answer (score 2):

Border does not have a foreground.  Remove TargetName from the equation... I believe it will work then.  It should look like below (also if this is a resource itt will need a key).  This worked fine my end.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="a" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="#FFDCDCC9" Background="#FFDCDCC9" BorderThickness="1">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                <Setter  Property="Background" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFB5266E"/>
                <Setter  Property="Background" TargetName="bg" Value="#FFEC94C0"/>
                <!-- foreground is invalid -->
                <Setter  Property="Foreground"  Value="white"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: No look at 6th row from bottom... Target Name is remove... DO NOT remove x:Name of the border.  If you remove the TargetName from the Setter item you XAML then looks at the control itself which is a TextBox.  Textbox has a foreground property.  Border does not

Comment: you can also set multi triggers if your problem is that "mouse over and IsFocused interfere with each other.  Obviously it will not interfere if there is no mouseover when textbox has focus etc.  But you can have MouseOver + Focus setters and MouseOver + Unfocus setters through multi triggers.

Comment: If I bind Textbox's Template to this control template and I run the project with exactly the same code as what I gave you.  When I "enter" the textbox to "type" the text is white.  What color is your text come up as?... does the other properties change when textbox has focus?  is there perhaps somewhere in code behind that you override this?

Comment: okay let me look at my code that probably overrides it. thanks for ur advice :)

Comment: For future FYI, it worked for me,  
`<Style x:Key="textStyleTextBox"
               TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                    <Setter  Property="Foreground"  Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>`